# What is the maximum number of requests one can make using Google Spreadsheet API?

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any limit on the number of request I can make in a day to the Google Spreadsheet API?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect no, or ... there might be an undocumented limit. But I have been using it for a while and have never seen any sign of a limit.

Comment: hopefully they don't +1, thanks for sharing your experience. how many requests you daily do aprox.?

Comment: 2 things: 1) request/day maybe 500, per hour maybe 200 .... 2) I suspect it runs on app engine, which drops a program from memory after 15mins, so how you use it would have an impact on google resources.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find a limit either after combing through their documentation.  Would be nice to know officially that there was no limit, though.

Answer (score 1):

the Google Sheets API has a default limit of 40,000 queries per day.

please refer this url  : 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.